# Geoportal Server 1.1.1 search widget for Flex 2.5

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer, geoportal

Does anyone one know where I can get the Geoportal Server 1.1.1 search widget for Flex 2.5?

I have been tasked with installing this to an existing geoportal server and Flex viewer does anyone know how to do this. I have found some instructions but they seem to require reloading the viewer. Any Ideas or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to this, http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5d4995ccdb99429185dfd8d8fb2a513e

Answer (score -1):

find it [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=64a6ee8023324b9097ea6970354a6a42) in the esri resource center ([code gallery](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/gallery.html))

Comment: Thanks Brad but that is for the gpt. extension not the server.